# Custom UITableViewCell changes when TableView scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with scrolling within the UITableView.
For this table, I created a custom UITableViewCell with 2 labels and 2 buttons.
The first label is a productname, the second label is the amount. The 2 buttons are + (plus) and - (minus) buttons.

**The situation**

The app is an order-system. When a customer wants a product, he/she taps the plus button. The minus-button
appears and the amount label grows with 1 (so from 0 to 1, or 1 to 2, etc.).

**The problem**

When a user scrolls through the table, the other cells changes to the cells who are 'selected' via the plus-button.
Hereby the user sees products that having an amount while he/she doens't want it at all.

--

What can I do to prevent the TableView from 'refreshing' the TableCells?

*The cellForRowAtIndexPath-method:*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductenCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductenCell  
    let object = productArray[indexPath.row]  
    cell.label.text = (object.valueForKey("productNaam") as! String)  

    // Plus-button  
    cell.plusKnop.addTarget(self, action: "productToevoegen:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)  
    cell.plusKnop.tag = indexPath.row  

    // Minus-button  
    cell.minKnop.addTarget(self, action: "productVerwijderen:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)  
    cell.minKnop.tag = indexPath.row  

    // Grey backgorund fo even cells  
    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 1) {  
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.961, green: 0.961, blue: 0.961, alpha: 1)  
    }  

    return cell  
}
```

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: I would have to see your plus and minus functions that get called on button click, but my guess is you are storing the value in the view, but when you scroll the view gets reused by another product's model.  All values should be stored in the model so that updating the view does not invalidate your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your values which is changing into your productArray or somewhere else, and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath restore this values into the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the model objects to store amount and update every cell according to model. It is wrong to store data in views.